# How do I safe data from an external database using guzzle?

Tags: php, guzzle

Currently I only can send a get request to the url, but how do i safe the requested data to my database?:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://xxxx.de/data');
echo $res->getStatusCode();
    
echo $res->getHeader('content-type')[0];

echo $res->getBody();

    $request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', 'https://xxxx.de/data');
    $promise = $client->sendAsync($request)->then(function ($response) {
    echo 'I completed! ' . $response->getBody();
});
$promise->wait();
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What data? You're just calling a URL.  "Safe" in what way? Are you asking how to use data from your database in your request, how to store the data in your database or something else? Please edit the question and explain in more detail what you're trying to do and what the actual question is.

Comment: Do you mean "save" rather than "safe"? It would make a lot more sense. The answer to how to save your data to the database is...use a sql query. Where exactly are you stuck? You can get the body from the response and pass it to the query. It's still not clear what the problem is, really.